# RoR: Trying to search by ID number or License Number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

hi so I'm trying to do 2 things, one of them is to basically redirect to a model's ID number so input is "1" and redirects to

```
localhost:3000/model/1
```

and the second part is actually doing a search. each model has a text field string for license_no and I want to be able to search and return results

currently, I am not sure how I would combine these into 1 search form if thats possible or if it would require 2 separate search forms

i have a search form with only the license_no field but it always returns no results found...

apologize that the model name isn't in singular, the guide I was using to learn RoR had it that way and everything worked, but I have so many references to renters in my project that it would be a while to find all of them

**index.html.erb**

```rb
<%= form_tag search_renters_path, method: get do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :license, nil, placeholder: "License Number" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: "btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

**models/renters.rb**

```rb
class Renters < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :license_no
    def self.search(params)
        renters = Renters.where("license_no LIKE?", "%#{params[:license]}%")
    end
end
```

**controller.rb**

```rb
def search
    @renter = Renters.search([params])
end
```

**search.html.erb - snippet**

```rb
<% if @renter.blank? %>
    no results
<% else %>
    #show results
<% end %>
```

**editted code**
**models/renters.rb**

```rb
  def self.search(params)
    license_query = "%#{params[:license]}%"
    id_query = "%#{params[:id]}%"
    renters = Renters.where("license_no LIKE ?", license_query) if params[:license].present?
    renters = Renters.where("id LIKE ?", id_query) if params[:id].present?
  end
```

**controller**

```rb
def search
  @renter = Renters.search(params)
end
```

**search form**

```rb
<%= form_tag search_renters_path, method: :get do |f| %>
                      <%= text_field_tag :license, nil, placeholder: "Driver's License" %>
                      <%= text_field_tag :id, nil, placeholder: "ID number" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to use the if present? statements to allow a user to decide whether to input ID No or License No. you don't need to input both just one. currently, if I search for a license no, it returns no results. but when I search for an ID, it returns the relevant result

Comment: try with `@renter = Renters.search(params)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this if you are getting value on `params[:licence]` from your form submit on your controller action `search`

**controller.rb**

```
def search
  @renter = Renters.search(params[:licence])
end
```

**app/models/renters.rb**

```
class Renters < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(query)
    like_query = "%#{query}%"
    renters = Renters.where("id LIKE ? OR license_no LIKE ?", like_query, like_query)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks I think this is the right track, but I would like to have kind of 2 different searches so if you know the license number you can fill in that field OR if you know the ID number you fill in that one, but usually not both fields. I think this way is requiring both fields to be searched?

Comment: okay .. how would you know which is which from a single text field (sent as `params[:licence]`) on your search form ?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't sure how to implement a second search field at the time, I added `<%= text_field_tag :id, nil, placeholder: "ID Number" %>`